# Blazor Server List behavior in Page load

Tags: c#, .net-5, blazor-server-side, blazor-component

I have a Blazor Server project in .NET 5 that is giving me some incredibly odd behavior in a particular page.

I have a page called `Products` which contains a custom component named `ProductSettings` that takes two lists - a `List<Location>` and a `List<Product>`. The page inherits from a `BasePage` which does some preliminary lookups (business info, etc.). The `Products` page looks like this:

```
<ProductSettings Products="@products" Locations="@locations"></ProductSettings>
```

I use the `OnParametersSet` methods for both page and component. The page method looks like this:

```cs
    protected List<Product> products { get; set; }
    protected List<string> locations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        log.LogTrace("Products.ParametersSet start");
        products = new List<Product>();
        locations = locationRepo.GetLocationsByBusiness(business!.BusinessId).Select(x => x.Handle).ToList();
        
        var l1 = productsRepo.GetProducts(locations[0], business!.BusinessId);
        
        log.LogTrace(@"{Loc0} location ids:",locations[0]);
        foreach (var l in l1)
        {
            log.LogTrace(l.LocationId);
        }

        var l2 = productsRepo.GetProducts(locations[1], business!.BusinessId);
        log.LogTrace(@"{Loc0} location ids:",locations[1]);
        foreach (var l in l2)
        {
            log.LogTrace(l.LocationId);
        }
        products.AddRange(l1);
        products.AddRange(l2);
        
        log.LogTrace("main array location ids:");
        foreach (var p in products)
        {
            log.LogTrace(p.LocationId);
        }
        log.LogTrace("Products page params set");
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
```

The `locationRepo.GetLocationsByBusiness` and `productsRepo.GetProducts` methods are synchronous and pull data out of Azure table storage.

The error I'm getting is, despite my loop going through and picking up `Product` data for each `Location` successfully (I have 2 locations each with 4 products), I end up with a list of 8 products that all match the second set of products. In other words, in the code above, I get this trace output:

```
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-1 location ids:
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-1
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-1
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-1
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-1

09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2 location ids:
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2

09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] main array location ids:
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
09:38:28 trce: AdminSite.Components.BasePage[0] business-2
```

For the life of me I cannot fathom why it is doing this. It appears to be completely overwriting the first four records in the List. I have other pages using a similar approach and I'm not running into any issues like this. Initially I thought it had something to do with other bits of logic in my repos or whatnot, and I've explored the documentation for `List<T>` but I can't find anything that says the objects would merge like this. I also have unit tests to verify and sanity check `AddRange` and my other logic, and everything is consistent in my libraries - only in this Blazor page am I getting this weirdness.

Comment: We can't really tell without seeing what `productsRepo.GetProducts` does. If that is where the Product instances come from, it's the probable culprit. `List.AddRange` does not ever modify the supplied instances in any way. Also, could you try to reproduce with something simple like a console app? I have a very strong suspicion this has nothing to do with Blazor as what you're getting is an error within normal C# code.

Comment: updated the code to simplify and highlight that the problem is coming out of Blazor and not the repo code (which I've tested numerous times at this point)

Comment: Thank you for adding more information and correcting me. Could you loop over `l1` *after* you fetch `l2` from the repo just to be absolutely sure?

Comment: Okay - so I did that and now they're both spit out the same values! Am I going mad or is there a simple explanation for this?!

Comment: The most probable explanation is that your `productsRepo` modifies the products returned from `GetProducts` on subsequent invocations.

Answer (score 0):

`ProductsRepo` had logic in it where it would look for products for a Location, and if they didn't exist, it would return a list of products for a `Business` (which is used as a default). The only plausible conclusion I could come up with is that by doing this somehow it was messing up the objects, which was very odd considering it passed unit testing after repeated testing of different scenarios.

The moral of the story here is probably to make separate calls for such things, which I should have had in the first place.